# Load read only recommended Excel file with batch file

Tags: excel, batch-processing

I'm building a batch file that loads a group of commonly used programs and docs, typically first thing in the a.m. One of the docs is an excel file with read only recommended, which I want to keep, so every time it opens it asks if it should be read only or not. Seems to me there should be a switch somewhere that I can use to answer that question so the user doesn't have to, but I can't find it. Anyone know of how to do this as a command line switch? Not really interested in using VBA if I don't have to. Windows 10, Excel 365. My current command line:

Start "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\excel.exe" "CTIScope Pricing Worksheet(2).xlsx"

I tried using the /R switch, but I just get an error: Invalid switch - "/R"

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE: I put the excel program folder in the PATH env. variable and changed the command line to:

Start excel "CTIScope Pricing Worksheet(2).xlsx"

and now it opens without the question, but in 'PROTECTED VIEW'. Not sure why and doubt if this is the answer, but solves my problem.

Comment: Why don't you try the /r inside the line with the worksheet name?

Comment: tried that. Just get an error that that file doesn't exist

Comment: Old post but somebody might need the answer to this. This [post](https://superuser.com/a/1261022/329564) might be the answer to this.